# Cordova file chooser for iOS?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ecmascript-6, cordova-plugins

Is there a way to open a file chooser in iOS when developing an application with Cordova and Ionic?
In Android I used `<input type="file" />` and Android allows me to access files and select a file, but in IOS? How can I open a file chooser? Is there any plugin or system already developed?

Comment: iOS doesn't really *have* a filesystem of that sort. You could try [this](https://github.com/jcesarmobile/FilePicker-Phonegap-iOS-Plugin) to access stuff in iCloud.

Comment: What about this? https://github.com/albertut/cordova-filepicker 
Can I use it for file picking in iOS? I can't understand why there's a file picker in other apps (not developed in Apache Cordova) and it allows user to select all files in the system, and there's not a file picker in Cordova... Can anybody explain me?

Comment: It'd help if you gave examples of these other apps. That one you've linked appears to be for a third-party service (https://www.filestack.com/).

Answer (score 2):

On iOS 9 and greater using the input type file will show you camera, photo library, icloud and any app installed on the device that are declared as a content providers (google drive, one drive, etc)

On iOS 8 you can use [this plugin I created](https://github.com/jcesarmobile/FilePicker-Phonegap-iOS-Plugin)

```
window.FilePicker.pickFile(successCallback,errorCallback);
```

Comment: just did a quick test now (iOS 10) and only got the photos options.  any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any content provider app installed?

Comment: not that i know of.  i am building in ionic though, if that makes a difference

Comment: never mind, i guess it's an ionic thing - in mobile browser i get the option for iCloud as well, just not within the app.  going to try setting up iCloud integration like you describe on github and see if that helps.  thanks!

Comment: i got the same issue even after i setup the iCloud integration. Did u fix it yet?

Comment: @DannyHo there is nothing to fix, iCloud doesn't appear you didn't to the integration steps correctly

Comment: @jcesarmobile Hi, i have setup the integration and got all tick for iCloud(both Xcode and developer website), is there any way that i can check if other setting is correct?

Comment: Are you testing on iOS 11? There is an issue open stating that it doesn't work on iOS 11. I have not tested it yet.

Comment: @jcesarmobile i am testing on ios10.3.3,It's strange that, if i logged-out iCloud, that option will appear, but disappear after login.

Comment: I using the ios 10.3.3 and If I took the archive(ipa), it does not show "iCloud" option. But If I run directly from xcode, It shows the iCloud drive option. Any Idea?